# Attempting to understand Python List Comprehesion order and assignment

Tags: python

I guess this more of a inquire than a question.

After spending a few hours working through some python examples I found something that has me questioning how Python List Comprehension works. I believe I have a grasp on the concept.

I know the following are the same:

```
ages = [19,15,16,72,43]
for t in range(len(ages)):
   ages[t] = ages[t] + 1
```

and :

```
ages = [19,15,16,72,43]
ages = [age +1 for age in ages]
```

Both will change ages to [20, 16, 17, 73, 44] as each item in the list ages is resigned to be equal to value++

But playing around and testing this I found:

```
>>> agegroups = [[4, 10, 45, 55, 62, 99, 102], \ 
                 [19, 56, 64, 74, 10, 29], \
                 [14, 75, 18, 19, 54, 29,2]]
>>> agegroups = [age.sort() for age in agegroups]
>>> agegroups
[None, None, None]
```

Will set the value of each list within agegroups to be 'None']

But using the following will sort each list within *agegroups*.

```
>>> agegroups = [[4, 10, 45, 55, 62, 99, 102], \ 
                     [19, 56, 64, 74, 10, 29], \
                     [14, 75, 18, 19, 54, 29, 2]]
>>> [age.sort() for age in agegroups]
 [None, None, None]
>>> agegroups
[[4, 10, 45, 55, 62, 99, 102], [10, 19, 29, 56, 64, 74], [2, 14, 18, 19, 29, 54, 75]]
```

I assume in the previous attempt, each list within agegroups is being assigned the return value *age.sort()*. Am I correct ?

Feel free to knock me around, new here and just stepping into the coils of Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the return value of `list.sort()` is always `None` and the list comprehension takes the value of the initial expression for each item in the list. In the case of e.g. `[x for x in list]` the initial expression is `x` so the value of `x` is put into the resulting list. In the case of `[x.sort() for x in lists]` the initial expresion is `x.sort()` so the value of `x.sort()` (that is, `None`) goes into the resulting list. Of course, the sublist is sorted first.

You can use the `sorted()` built-in function to make a sorted copy to put into the list comprehension:

```
[sorted(x) for x in lists]
```

Or you can use this construction to call `x.sort()` first and then return `x` to put the sorted `x` into the resulting list:

```
[x.sort() or x for x in lists]
```

This works because `x.sort()` always returns `None`, `None` is falsey, and so the other branch of the `or` is always evaluated and returns the value `x`.

A final thing you can do is to just use a generator expression and have it consumed by the `any()` built-in function.

```
any(x.sort() for x in lists)
```

This sorts each sublist, but doesn't do anything with the `None` values -- they just vanish. No new list is created. `any()` stops at the first truthy value, and there are never any truthy values because `x.sort()` always returns `None` which is falsey, so in this case `any()` is guaranteed to iterate through the entire generator. `any()` returns either `True` or (in this case) `False`, which we also throw away. So you find each sublist in `lists` sorted, and `lists` contains the sublists in the same order as before, since it was not changed. It is essentially the same as:

```
for x in lists: x.sort()
```

Comment: I suspect that `[x.sort() or x for x in lists]` might also be faster that using `[sorted(x) for x in lists]` since it doesn't have to create a bunch of new sub-lists.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's right, at least if your lists are of any substantial size at all. I have also added a generator-based version using `any()` which avoids creating any new lists at all.

Comment: Thank you, I have to play around with those concepts and make a few notes.  This is an amazing scripting language.

Comment: Yes, I really love Python. It does have a few warts, but far fewer than most other languages, and even the warts are often (ab)usable as features.

Answer (score 0):

list.sort() is a self-mutating method that doesn't return anything, thus the None. list.sort() operates on the list itself and changes its state.

If you wanted to get a clone of each list, you would probably be better of with sorted(list)

```
[sorted(age) for age in agegroups]
```

Answer (score 0):

The sort method of lists is an in-place method, meaning it does not return a value but it does affect the order of the list. You should try using the sorted method instead which is similar but it does actually return a value:

```
[sorted(ages) for ages in agegroups]
```